# Do Fall Courses Count in PhD Admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, coursework

I am currently an undergraduate at a university. I am looking at graduate programs in Mathematics, and if I am applying for math graduate programs for the year 2014-2015, are fall courses (2013) taken into consideration for graduate applications?

If so, could you elaborate according to your knowledge and experiences. I'm sure this question is applicable to other graduate programs other than Mathematics, so any comments pertaining to this question would be appreciated.

Comment: where are you considering applying to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to tell if fall grades will be taken into account is to *look at the application instructions*. If you see instructions asking you to provide your mid-year grades, then that's a pretty clear indication that they will be taken into account during the admissions process. If you are not asked to submit it, then follow that guideline.

If it's *optional* for whatever reason, I would assume that you should plan as if it were a mandatory submission.